# How to compile namespace in remote REPL

Tags: clojure, nrepl

I have a problem compiling `.clj` files which reside in a project where I run the nREPL server process:

1. I've created a new project using `lein new xxx`.
2. In the project folder I started up an nREPL by `lein repl`.
3. In another terminal window I started a client `lein repl :connect localhost:12345/repl`.
4. I created a simple namespace file and saved it inside the project in the appropriate location:

   ```
   (ns remote.one)
   (def foo 42)
   ```
5. Now on the client terminal I called this function

   ```
   (compile 'remote.one)
   ```

I've got the below exception:

```
CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: remote.one, compiling:(C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\form-init2429492334116477513.clj:1:1)
```

Now I would have expected the compile call to be executed in the server not on the client. Can it be done at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it and it worked for me. What happened the first time I tried it was that I missed a step: setting the current directory as the project's. I see that this step is also missing from your description, maybe that's the reason it doesn't work in your case.

1. Create a new project using `lein new remote`.
2. **Change the current directory `cd remote`.**
3. Start the nREPL server from the project folder with `lein repl :headless` **(which I realize now is also different from your description)**.
4. Open a new console and start the nREPL client `lein repl :connect localhost:port/repl` in `~/.`.
5. Create the file for the ns in `~/remote/src/remote/one.clj`.
6. From the client evaluate `(compile 'remote.one)`.

(Using `Leiningen 2.3.4 on Java 1.7.0 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM` and `Clojure 1.5.1`).

Comment: The remote REPL was started in the project folder, I only omitted that step from my description. Did you start the client from the same folder? Just to make it clear, I got the exception in the client process.

Comment: @Janos Just updated the answer since I realized I actually started the nREPL server with the `:headless` flag.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :( It still looks for the clj file in the temp folder. However, if I start up the client in the same directory (that of the project's) then it works fine. Of course, this is not an option.

Comment: Will try it using JDK 1.7 and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Juan, are you sure you are not starting the client repl in the project's folder? (Still I'm going to try with 1.7 JDK)

Comment: It does work. I had such a schoolboy error that I'm hesitant to tell: I wrote ('compile blah.blah) instead of (compile 'blah.blah)...

Comment: @Janos :) it happens. Glad the answer helped!